# Spring Boot 3.1 with Jetty: Invalid SNI

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I'm in process of migration to Spring Boot 3 from Spring Boot 2.7, but my services are killed by the orchestrator on failing healthchecks:

```
/health org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Invalid SNI
```

Considering nothing changed on how orchestrator calls health endpoint, I can't find anything related in upgrade notes

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with [customization](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36271#issuecomment-1633026101) of WebServerFactory

```java
@ManagementContextConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class DisableSniHostCheckConfiguration {

    @Bean
    WebServerFactoryCustomizer<JettyServletWebServerFactory> disableSniHostCheck() {
        return (factory) -> {
            factory.addServerCustomizers((server) -> {
                for (Connector connector : server.getConnectors()) {
                    if (connector instanceof ServerConnector serverConnector) {
                        HttpConnectionFactory connectionFactory = serverConnector
                            .getConnectionFactory(HttpConnectionFactory.class);
                        if (connectionFactory != null) {
                            SecureRequestCustomizer secureRequestCustomizer = connectionFactory.getHttpConfiguration()
                                .getCustomizer(SecureRequestCustomizer.class);
                            if (secureRequestCustomizer != null) {
                                secureRequestCustomizer.setSniHostCheck(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }

}
```

and `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration.imports` file with:

```
com.mypackage.DisableSniHostCheckConfiguration
```

Make sure the package is scanned